# How to get the languages installed in "Region and Languages"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm working on a chrome extension that takes text from text boxes 
in an html page and converts it to any other wanted language i have installed on my "Region and Languages" under control settings.

is there any easy way to get the languages installed on the "Region and Languages" through chrome extension ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

Chrome's language settings are separate from system-wide language settings. You can see Chrome's settings at `chrome://settings/languages`

However, you can access Chrome's language settings with `chrome.i18n`:

```
chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages(function(langs) {
  // langs is an array of languages
});
```